# Keras: Make functional model accept multiple batches for LSTM

Tags: python, keras

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import tensorflow.keras.layers as layers
import tensorflow.keras as keras
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

def get_model():

    inputs = layers.Input(batch_shape=(1, 200, 12)) #input
    
    x = layers.LSTM(12, return_sequences=True, stateful=True)(inputs)
    outputs = layers.TimeDistributed(layers.Dense(2, activation="softmax"))(x)
    model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(), metrics=['accuracy'])
    print(model.summary())
    return model

model = get_model()

x_train = np.ones((10,200,12))
x_val = np.ones((10,200,12))
y_train = np.ones((10,200,2))
y_val = np.ones((10,200,2))

history = model.fit(x_train, y_train,
                    epochs=40,
                    validation_data=(x_val, y_val),
                    verbose=2)
```

Gives me this output

```
InvalidArgumentError:  [_Derived_]  Specified a list with shape [1,12] from a tensor with shape [10,12]
     [[{{node TensorArrayUnstack/TensorListFromTensor}}]]
     [[model_19/lstm_47/StatefulPartitionedCall]] [Op:__inference_train_function_78329]
```

If I make x_train and x_val shape (1,200,12) it works fine. How do I make the input object accept multiple batches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to specify the batch_size like so...

```
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train,
                    epochs=40,
                    validation_data=(x_val, y_val),
                    verbose=2,
                    batch_size=1
)
```